# Why am I getting a TokenError when authenticating with OAuth2Strategy for Passport/Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to use the OAuth2Strategy for Passport JS in conjunction with Express (4).

After I'm redirected to to login, it successfully navigates me back to my callback url, at which point I get the following error:

```
TokenError: Invalid client or client credentials
    at OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:298:12)
    at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:345:16)
    at /www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:171:43
    at /www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18 at passBackControl (/www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:124:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/www/az-avatarz-server/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:919:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
```

My passport configuration is as follows:

```
passport.use("avatarz", new OAuth2Strategy({
        authorizationURL: authorizationURL,
        tokenURL: tokenURL,
        clientID: clientID,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: callbackURL
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.find({
            prid: profile.prid
        }, function (error, user) {
            if (error) {
                return done(error);
            }

            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else {
                done(error);
            }
        });
    }
));
```

And my routes are as follows:

```
app.get('/authentication/provider', passport.authenticate("avatarz"));

app.get('/', passport.authenticate("avatarz", { failureRedirect: '/authentication/provider' }),
function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("./public/index.html");
});
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had the exact same symptom when I incorrectly specified the Client secret. 

Perhaps double check that it is the same as the Client secret for your project at https://console.developers.google.com/.

Comment: ^ the above was my problem as well!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have activated the Google+ API at:  https://console.developers.google.com